# How to ignore storybook addon error in typescript?

Tags: typescript, storybook

I am using `storybook` in a typescript react project and I am facing some compiling error like

`Could not find a declaration file for module '@storybook/addon-actions'. '/material-ui-es/node_modules/@storybook/addon-actions/dist/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.`

They are from storybook addons. How can I fix the error if the addons doesn't support type. Or I'd like to ignore them since they are not part of production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm also using Storybook in my projects and to fix this problem I add types

```
"devDependencies": {
    ...
    "@types/storybook__addon-actions": "^3.4.2",
    "@types/storybook__react": "^4.0.1",
    "apollo-storybook-react": "^0.2.1",
    ...
},
```

and if there are no types, I declare the module on `typings.d.ts`

```
declare module 'apollo-storybook-react';
declare module '@storybook/addon-console';
```